# Visual Studio bug resolving lambda in method with Func delegate overloads?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda, func, overload-resolution

I've come across some strange behaviour in Visual Studio 2010 when using anonymous methods in functions that have overloads of various Func delegates.

I've created a small reproduction class below.

Consider this ListViewAdapter class

```
namespace LambdaTestApp
{
    public class ListViewAdapter<T>
    {
        private Func<int, string, int, string> _converter1;
        private Func<RefType1, string, string> _converter2;

        public ListViewAdapter(int arg1, Func<int, string, int, string> converter) 
        {
            _converter1 = converter;
        }

        public ListViewAdapter(int arg1, Func<RefType1, string, string> converter) 
        {
            _converter2 = converter;
        }

        public static ListViewAdapter<T> MockPopulate(int arg, Func<int, string, int, string> converter) {

            ListViewAdapter<T> instance = new ListViewAdapter<T>(arg, converter);

            return instance;
        }

        public static ListViewAdapter<T> MockPopulate(int arg, Func<RefType1, string, string> converter)
        {
            ListViewAdapter<T> instance = new ListViewAdapter<T>(arg, converter);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public class RefType1
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**And this following code that uses the overload with a lambda:**

```
namespace LambdaTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListViewAdapter<RefType1>.MockPopulate(1, (item, str) =>
            {
                var myItem = item;
                return str;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It should resolve to `Func<RefType1, string, string>` and the first argument should be `RefType1`, however the issue is that instead of `item` being a `RefType1` Visual Studio sees it as an `int`.

Question: Is there a valid conversion between the Func delegates that isn't obvious, or is this a Visual Studio IntelliSense bug?

Comment: Look for other errors in the lambda.

Comment: Right, does the code compile?  Get it to compile first and then work backwards from there to understand what's going on.  Usually easier that way with generics and overloads.

Comment: Side note: when you have more than 10 method parameters, you are probably missing some others. Those parameters should be refactored into some kind of `Args` class

Comment: @GETah, where do you see these "10" method parameters?  (I count 5, which is a perfectly reasonable number)

Comment: @SLaks The lambda was complete in my example, however I have posted additional relevant code.

Comment: What is the data type of _collection[position]? Set a break point on it, then hover the mouse over it.

Comment: @MikeHofer _collection is a List<T> so it's a Technician, however my issue is a design time issue because I can't access items's Technician methods and properties without creating a compile error (unless I cast it, which defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place)

Comment: @KirkWoll To me, more than 3 parameters is a design smell! Why would a method need more than 3 parameters?

Comment: @GETah, don't be ridiculous.  Look at approximately half the methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.  It's much better to evaluate individually the proper design for a given method rather than trying to come up with "code smells" that try to encourage you to adopt a design without having to bother to think it through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally agree that it's a bug - or at least a *flaw*. Even though it only shows up when the code is invalid - and it's only when the code *within the lambda expression* is invalid - I think it would be more appropriate for Intellisense to view the parameter declaration part of the lambda expression (the part before `=>`) as complete, and work based on that information.

There's nothing you can put within the *body* of the lambda expression which would change the overload resolution in a way which would make the choice of `Func<int, string, int, string>` valid... there just aren't enough parameters.

I would *at least* suggest logging a [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) issue about this - it may well be "working as intended" in terms of "MS didn't design it to cope with this scenario" but it could clearly work better. Note that it's still working this way in the VS11 beta, although admittedly the laptop I'm running on at the moment hasn't applied the recent update to the beta. I wouldn't be surprised if you got a response which amounted to "Yes, that would be nice - but it would take a huge amount of work for little gain" but it's worth raising anyway, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

> It should resolve to `Func<RefType1, string, string>` and the first argument should be `RefType1`, however the issue is that instead of item being a `RefType1` Visual Studio sees it as an `int`.

Visual Studio *guesses* it as an `int` as long as there is a compilation error, by looking at the first of the overloaded functions. It cannot determine which overload is used, because it cannot understand the code. It might be able to do a better job at guessing which one you *probably* meant, but it's a bit harsh to consider this a bug.

When you fix the error, Visual Studio can tell that the argument type is `RefType1`. You can verify this by making sure the code compiles, and then hovering the mouse over `item`.

Yes, unfortunately that means that since typing `.` will at least temporarily make the code invalid, and will display the members of `int`. If you really need to, you can call `item.ToString();` in a way that satisfies the compiler, and then overwrite the `.` with a new `.`. You'll then see the list you're hoping for.

Alternatively, make sure your most commonly used overload is listed first, to make Visual Studio guess differently.

Comment: Harsh to call it a bug? Intellisense is showing the wrong information, that is clearly a bug.

Comment: @payo It's not all that wrong to not be able to select an overload when the code is invalid, IMO.

Comment: @hvd What you are saying makes no sense at all. The whole point of IntelliSense is to provide information so you know how to type valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Method overload resolution for LINQ works *exactly* like it does for C#: based on number and types of arguments, and nothing more. Whether or not an argument is generic is irrelevant.

Without seeing the code in `PopulateListView`, I'd have to say that you're passing an int, and that's what you're getting.

Comment: `Func` has one more generic type argument than it has parameters: the return type is also a generic type argument.

Comment: @hvd: You know, I *know* that, and should have known better than to write it. I work with Func<T, ...> all day. Thanks for the correction. I've edited to remove senseless stupidity.

Comment: @MikeHofer I've updated/revised the question with different code.

Comment: @dmck Although it wasn't directed at me, thanks, I somehow didn't understand the question at first, but I think I do now.